# Load Internal Assets from HTML File inside UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

In my app built in Xcode 8.2 I have a controller with the web view where web view loads an internal HTML file like this:

```
    let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "web/place-info", ofType: "html")
    var htmlString = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    self.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString!, baseURL: nil)
```

Then I want to include some additional JavaScript and CSS into that HTML file but the file fails to load any. The including path seems to be either wrong or blocked.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="web/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

What is more strange is that this image will never load inside place-info.html BODY tag:

```
        <img src="ic-user-profile.png" />
        <img src="/ic-user-profile.png" />
        <img src="img/ic-user-profile.png" />
        <img src="/img/ic-user-profile.png" />
        <img src="web/img/ic-user-profile.png" />
        <img src="/web/img/ic-user-profile.png" />
        <img src="Project-Name/web/img/ic-user-profile.png" />
        <img src="/Project-Name/web/img/ic-user-profile.png" />
        <img src="Project-Name/Project-Name/web/img/ic-user-profile.png" />
        <img src="/Project-Name/Project-Name/web/img/ic-user-profile.png" />
```

Am I missing some special setting in Xcode 8.2? Note that in settings I already have `App Transport Security Settings` to be `Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES`

Comment: What is the folder structure for your files?  if 'web' is a folder name in `let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "web/place-info", ofType: "html")` remove it to only be: --`let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "place-info", ofType: "html")` . Also I would consider using a WKWebView instead of a UIWebView, you get a performance boost with your javascript.  Then you will need to use `webView.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")` on your [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is that you pass nil as `baseURL` and only give the web view a string to load. It can't possibly know the location from where to load files referenced by relative links.

So just pass the folder where `place-info.html` is located as base URL:

```
let baseURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "web", withExtension: nil)!
let contentURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("place-info.html")
let htmlString = try? String(contentsOf: contentURL, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
self.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString!, baseURL: baseURL)
```

Then, relative links like

- `<img src="ic-user-profile.png" />`
- `<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

will load the resources from locations relative to your `web` folder. Note that I removed `web/` from your stylesheet href, assuming that the `web` folder contains `font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`:

```
web/
 |- place-info.html
 |- ic-user-profile.png
 |- font-awesome/
      |- css/
          |- font-awesome.min.css
```

Adding to Jacob Boyd's comment, please also note the [UIWebView API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview) states

> In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWeb​View class instead of using UIWeb​View.

Which is further emphasized by [WKWebView's API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview):

> **Important**
>   Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView.